# angular single page app, how do I handle the user leaving page then pressing back?

Tags: angularjs

I have a single page angular app that has links to pdfs in it.  when the user clicks on them, they fill the screen and if they press back, the angular app restarts rather than resuming where it use to be.

What i am trying is to use window.onbeforeunload to store the data from my controllers in the browsers local storage before my SPA is unloaded and then I restore the data when i catch the route when the back button is pressed.

The problem i have is if there are multiple tabs on the browser with my app open, then they all think that that they need to restore the data from the local storage.

is there a better way to handle the user going to another url then pressing back?
should i be trying to catch a browser back button event to see if i should reload the data from local storage?

Comment: what kind of 'state' are you trying to persist between page reloads?

Comment: its a fairly complex app, so there is fair amount of data. some examples.  list of email results based on several filters.  user information like name, email and photo url. and much more.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a separate url for openining pdfs.

You could setup PdfController for example which has function openPDf(url, $location) and set the $location to the pdf url.

Comment: i dont see how this helps. its all about angular saving and restoring state when you leave the angular page for the pdf and then press back.  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/XBOtriLeo0Y   this document says reloading a page === restarting application

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time the 'state' of the page can be saved in the **url** parameters. This will also makes your page **bookmarkable**.

For example, if you have a search box for the list of pdfs, just embed the query in the url/route parameters:

```
#/pdfs?query=abc
```

Then, when the user loads that url, from a bookmark or using the back button, you will be able to restore the filter.

You can use `$location.search()` to save the state when it changes, and then read it back when the controller loads.

```
.controller('PdfsCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.query = $location.search().query;
    $scope.$watch('query', function(value, old) {
        $location.search('query', value);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks gargc.  for smaller apps yes, you could save the values on the url.  i have a very large app with many controllers and a fair amount of model data so the url either wouldnt work or would be amazingly large

Comment: right :) it depends on what data you have, of course. That is why I asked about that in the comment above, i wasn't sure if the url solution would work for your case.